# How to create a Windows Media Player plugin in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-media-player

I've been trying to create a Windows Media Player plugin in Visual Studio 2008, and am having great difficulty finding the correct template. MSDN provides advice [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb262076(VS.85).aspx), but it does not appear to be relevant to VS2008.

Can anyone suggest how to start a WMP plugin in Visual Studio?

EDIT: Ive accepted this answer because it worked for me, but I'm afraid it isn't the most elegant of solutions. If anyone has a better idea, please add it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the platfrom SDK,  it has a bunch of example examples.  But none of them are likely to be updated for VS2008,  but that doesn't matter too much, its easy to convert the projects.

Answer (score 1):

See this post on the MSDN forums:

http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2627171&SiteID=1

Basically follow the instructions here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb262326(VS.85).aspx using the VS2005 wizard.

Then edit wmpwiz.vsz so that the first line reads Wizard=VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.9.0